# Is this the right way to passively assign categories to an entity

Tags: mysql, object, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am trying to design a database which can be used to 'passively' identify (and optionally assign) any/all categories that an object fits into. The below is the way I'm currently implementing it but not having done this before, I wanted to see if anyone has a better idea of how to go about doing it. I am using Symfony with MySQL and Doctrine.

**1/. Tables that define the objects:**

An <kbd>Element</kbd> table that contains features that an animal could have. This table will evolve over time - eg as animals that have wings are added:

```
ID NAME   CRITERIA
1  Leg    0-100
2  Arm    0-2
3  Pouch  Boolean
4  Horn   0-2
```

An <kbd>Animal</kbd> table that give individual information on each animal in the database:

```
ID NAME      Gender Weight DOB
1  Gertrude  F      450    2010-01-01
2  Shiela    F      200    2008-01-01
3  Bruce     M      250    2012-01-01
```

An <kbd>Identity</kbd> table to assign which <kbd>Elements</kbd> are assigned to each <kbd>Animal</kbd>:

```
ANIMALID  ELEMENTID COUNT DESCRIPTION
1         1         4     
1         4         0                       
2         1         2     
2         2         2     
2         3         True                    // Female kangaroo has a pouch
3         1         2     Strong hind legs
3         2         2     
3         3         False                   // Male kangaroo has no pouch
```

---

The above I am clear with. However, I want to be able to passively identify/assign the categories that the current object meets the required criteria for. Ideally, as the user is filling in the form to create a new <kbd>Animal</kbd> they would be able to see a list of which categories they are currently meeting the criteria for as they add/remove <kbd>Element</kbd> (eg Cow, Mammal, Bovine, Quadruped).

---

To continue the example:

**2/. Tables that define the categories:**

A <kbd>Class</kbd> table to define the required attributes of a category:

```
ID NAME           WEIGHTMIN WEIGHTMAX HEIGHTMIN HEIGHTMAX AgeMax
1  Adult Cow      220       1000      .         200       50
2  Kangaroo       .         100       .         .         .
```

A <kbd>Class_Feature</kbd> table which additionally defines mandatory features of a <kbd>Class</kbd> through a one-to-many association that are additionally required. Note: `GROUPID` identifies groups of required features and `SUBGROUPOF` identifies if the options are nested under an additional mandatory requirement (such as with male/female cows having horns):

```
CLASSID GROUPID SUBGROUPOF ELEMENTID  GENDER MIN   MAX
1       1       .          2          .      0     0        // A cow can't have any arms
1       2       1          4          M      1     2        // Male cows have horns 
1       2       1          4          F      0     0        // Female cow can not have horns
2       1       .          3          M      0     0 
2       1       .          3          F      1     1
```

Comment: An EAV is notoriously difficult to with. If you are going to pursue this model, consider having separate tables for each data type.

Comment: Hi @Strawberry thanks for the comment...I hadn't heard of EAV but having just had a read through, is this then a triplestore?

Comment: I don't know what a triplestore is.